# Google Play user review app version not matching installed version

Tags: android, google-play, version, review

We have an app where sometimes we force users to update the app, in case it's absolutely necessary, so users don't use old app. However we still, quiet often, receive reviews that indicates old app versions. This is confusing. How does Google determine the number to be place below the review.

I have several devices. On one device I have version 5.0 installed, but once I place the comment from that device number 6.0 appears under the review, so it's definitely not the app version installed on the device, that's being written under the review, but I'm having problems understanding, where is the number coming from? Is there such thing as "default device" for user, it's getting the number from?

Shedding any light on the issue is very welcome.

Comment: possibly. do you have other devices with other versions installed under the same account? For other users, reviews of the latest version are more relevant, so if you actually have the latest version, that makes sense to assume that is the version you are reviewing